# How do I stream alaw audio?

Tags: android, wav

I have a source that streams wav audio in alaw format which I would like to receive in Android, but Android only supports linear PCM: [Android Supported Media Formats](http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html)

There are a few apps on the market that stream alaw, but I'm not sure how the developers made it happen.  What is the correct approach to adding this functionality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably a little late, but doing 16-bit Linear PCM to 8-bit alaw or ulaw is pretty straightforward: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G.711.  You could either use a 256-value lookup table (probably the easiest), or implement the "algorithm" directly.